# Python counter for inner class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-classes

I am looking a way to count the number of instances of the `Inner` class for each instance of the `Outer` class.

Here are the classes and the test I performed:

```
class Outer:
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    class Inner:
        inner_counter = 0
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.id = Outer.Inner.inner_counter
            Outer.Inner.inner_counter += 1
```

```
c0 = Outer()
print(f"c0 : {c0.Inner.inner_counter}")

c0a = c0.Inner()
print(f"c0 : {c0.Inner.inner_counter}")

c1 = Outer()
print(f"c1 : {c1.Inner.inner_counter}")
```

I get this result:

```
c0 : 0
c0 : 1
c1 : 1
```

Instead of this, I would like to have:

```
c0 : 0
c0 : 1
c1 : 0
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your English is fine and your problem statement is pretty clear.

Comment: My English was corrected by a reviewer. Thanks for his suggestions!

Comment: Fair enough. It's not perfect, but clear enough, which is all that matters.

Answer (score 3):

Class scopes are isolated from enclosing class scopes because of how python code is executed. When the interpreter encounters `class Outer:`, it creates a new namespace to execute the class body in. The class object itself does not get created until the `class` block is exited. That means that by the time `class Inner:` is exited and `Inner` is created, `Outer` does not exist yet.

In short, Python nested classes behave nothing like nested classes in say Java, which can belong to an instance of the outer class. You can see this in your code, where you have to access `Outer.Inner` from the global scope to get your class. Your definition could have been written equivalently as follows:

```
class Inner:
    inner_counter = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Inner.inner_counter
        Inner.inner_counter += 1

class Outer:
    pass
```

If you want a counter for each instance of `Outer`, you need to maintain the counter in that instance. Here is an example:

```
class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inner_counter = 0

    def make_inner(self):
        return self._Inner(self)
    
    class _Inner:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent  # this line is optional
            self.id = parent._inner_counter
            parent._inner_counter += 1
```

Here, the factory method `make_inner` is used to construct `_Inner` objects in preference to calling `Outer._Inner`. I suggest marking `_inner_counter` and `_Inner` with leading underscores to let users know that they are implementation-dependent attributes that they shouldn't touch.

This is the straightforward implementation. If you want to simulate the behavior of the code in your question, you can create a `property` (or other descriptor, `property` is just so convenient) for `Inner` to contain the factory method:

```
from functools import partial

class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._inner_counter = 0

    @property
    def Inner(self):
        return partial(self._Inner, self)

    class _Inner:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent
            self.id = parent._inner_counter
            parent._inner_counter += 1

        @property
        def inner_counter(self):
            return self.parent._inner_counter
```

With this version, you can run the original code exactly to get the desired result. I would recommend dropping the `inner_counter` property entirely and accessing the counter directly as `_inner_counter` on the `Outer` object.

Totally irrelevant, but your printouts would look cleaner using f-strings:

```
c0 = Outer()
print(f"c0 : {c0._inner_counter}")

c0a = c0.Inner()
print(f"c0 : {c0._inner_counter}")

c1 = Outer()
print(f"c1 : {c1._inner_counter}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do you manage the child class of _Inner? The Outer class contain in fact several child class of _Inner.

Comment: @Feiser. That really depends on how you want to handle it. Same counter, different counters, etc. I would suggest asking a separate question, since the code for different counters would be a bit different.